# Asp.Net View State persisted?

Tags: asp.net, persistence, viewstate

Is it a good idea to persist all ViewStates of the Intranet in a Memcached or directly in file on the server like this [article](http://aspalliance.com/911_Store_View_State_in_a_Persistent_Medium_the_Proper_Way) show?

I usually see it directly in pages but a lot of our pages (Intranet website for clients) have huge DataGrid (can make the page up to 2 megs).

Is it a good way to have smaller page? Any problem that you can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ideal way I've found is to use the `PageStatePersister`:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131036/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011707-1.aspx

The only thing to consider is history size.  I've gone with 20 and never have performance issues.

Comment: Well you are the only one that seem to do it :p I'll accept but not sure if I will do it.

Comment: It's a good solution and will give you a smaller page especially when you have a datagrid or other complex control tucking itself into the viewstate.  It won't be a problem at all because this is actually part of core 2.0 on.  Just make sure you use the History size to deal with back button issues.